# Add Css Class to ActionLink of ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

In ASP.NET MVC3 This is a regular actionlink at Razor view :

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
```

and related html dom is:

```
<li><a href="/HomePage/">Home</a></li>
```

So my css work correctly if I add css class to the `<a>` element like the following:

```
<li><a class="MyCssClass" href="/HomePage/">Home</a></li>
```

Does any one know how can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this to pass in html attributes.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new { @class = "MyCssClass" })
```

You can pass other html attributes as well.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new { @class = "MyCssClass", otherAttributeName = 1 })
```

**hope this helps**

Answer (score 3):

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new { @class = "myclass" })</li>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a newer version of the ASP.NET MVC framework, you will have to pass an extra parameter for the routeValues. There's no method signature overload that accepts htmlAttributes as the 4th parameter any more, so if you are not passing in routeValues, just pass in a null like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = "MyCssClass" })
```

Answer (score 1):

Use another overload:

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new { @class="YourClass" })</li>
```