# Calling a GET method in api controller from the view in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I want to call a method in the Web API controller on click of a button by passing the filename and GUID associated with the button in the View.

Here is the code.

```
<div style="float: left; width: 75%; margin-left: 10px;">

@(Html.Telerik().Grid((IEnumerable<FileModel>)ViewData["DocumentList"]).Name("DocumentList").Template(@text @Html.ActionLink("FileDownload", "FileDownload", new { file = item.FileName, GuID = item.DocumentGuID }) /text).Width(10);
```

In the above code I was calling `FileDownload` Action by passing  `FileName` and `GUID` as parameters.
Now I want to call a method in `samplecontroller` and pass "`Filename`" and "`Guid`" as parameters.

```
public samplecontroller:webapicontroller
{
    public downLoad(int,guid)
}
```

How can I call the method "`downLoad`" on click of button in view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With ApiController most probably you need to use javascript to call the method async. Jquery will help Something like below:

```
Jquery script inside the view, in document on load function:
    $('#buttonid').bind('click', function(){
            var filename = $('#file').attr('name');
        var guid = $('#file').attr('guid');
        $.getJSON("api/samplecontroller/download?file=" + filename +"&guid=" +guid,
            function (data) {
                // On success

            });

    });

Controller action:  
    public samplecontroller:Apicontroller
    {
        public Download([fromuri]string fileName, [fromuri]string guid)
        {

        }
    }
```

There are other options though on how you pass the filename and guid and format the Uri request with UriTemplate.

Comment: Can I call the jquery function within the grid i.e.,within html.Telerik() tag?

Comment: The better way is to use javascript the unobtrusive way[link]http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript So tag your button or link with a class or ID when you render the grid items. If there are many similar items then assign a dummy class to all items like 'mybtnclass' instead of ID. Then you can bind a event with the class like: $('.mybtnclass').bind('click', function(){..});

Comment: Here is how you can add a class to your action link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490310/add-css-class-to-actionlink-of-asp-net-mvc